# simple modal not scroll background <body>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, simplemodal

I'm using [simple modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/). Is there any way to keep the background (behind the overlay) from scrolling when you roll the mouse wheel while outside the boundaries of the modal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While creating the modal, set `overflow:hidden` for body. Then you will not be able to scroll the background and when hiding the modal, set `overflow:auto` for `body`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', '.simplemodal-overlay, .simplemodal-data', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm not sure if `mousewheel` has full cross-browser support, though.

**Edit:** I verified this works, but you need the `mousewheel` plugin:  https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/downloads

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/AhpLc/

(I pasted `jquery.mousewheel.min.js` into the script area... Don't do that)

Comment: ah. works pretty well. thanks! the problem is that the modal has got a couple boxes with scrollbars in them. so when you use the mousewheel within them, when you hit the bottom, the page in the background still scrolls. is there a way to modify the selection so that those scrolls work and nothing else does when the modal is up? thanks again!

Comment: That turns out to be a lot harder, because `mousewheel` doesn't conform to the normal event bubbling/propagation as other events.  I have yet to figure out an easy way to do this.